# Unable to getDateTime() from DateTimePicker

Tags: blackberry, java-me, date-format, datetimepicker

I am using `DateTimePicker` to Select Date and Time and when I press the **ok** button getting Date time by using getDateTime() and assigning it to Calender object(`selectedDate`). I want to display the Time in the format (*fri apr 27 06:00:00 am*).

So I am using below code to format.

```
selectedDate = datePicker.getDateTime();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE   MMM  dd hh:mm:ss aa");
timeField.setText(sdf.formatLocal(selectedDate.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND)));
```

Don't know whether it is a parsing error or `DateTimePicker` returning the wrong time but Text displayed for any date time select is

> Thu Jan 01 05:00:00 AM.

As I have to target Most devices, My app targeting OS5 and testing on Simulator 9550.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are retrieving **just** the value of the current date's `MILLISECOND` field, not the whole date.  You probably want millisecond *precision*, but this code

```
selectedDate.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND)
```

is simply [extracting the milliseconds field from the current date/time](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29).  This is only the number of milliseconds since the previous second.   Similar to how

```
selectedDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

would simply return 4 today (or maybe it returns 3, I can't remember if it's 0-based).

You should use

```
timeField.setText(sdf.formatLocal(selectedDate.getTime().getTime()));
```

Comment: I couldn't found a method getTimeInMillis() in the API. I see in in the Calendar API given on blackberry.com but not while writing the code in eclipse.

Comment: @TNR, Try it again (see update above).  `getTimeInMillis()` is **protected**, which is why you can't *find* it.  `getTime().getTime()` is what you want instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. all your answers helped us very much.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand your question, since you don't tell us what happens that you don't expect and/or any error message that you get; further, I cannot find formatLocal() as a method on SimpleDateFormat anywhere.

I do notice you appear to be passing it the *portion* of the date that is in milliseconds.  If you want the date represented as milliseconds, the method for that is Date.getTime().

Comment: BlackBerry Java is a subset of standard Java (J2ME -> Java 1.3).  [Here is the API doc for formatLocal()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/i18n/DateFormat.html#formatLocal%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20long%29)

Comment: You're right, it is getTimeInMillis() instead of getTime() -- I saw the name included the term "Date" and missed the fact that he told us it was a Calendar object.